# Python: Appending a to a list from a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

This is going to be long but I don't know how else to effectively explain this.

So I have 2 files that I am reading in. The first one has a list of characters.The second file is a list of 3 characters and then it's matching identifier character(separated by a tab).

With the second file I made a dictionary with the 3 characters as the items and the one character as the corresponding key. 
What I need to do is take 3 characters at a time from the first list and compare it with the dictionary. If there is a match I need to take the corresponding key and append it to a new list that I will print out. If the match is a '*' character I need to stop not continue comparing the list to the dictionary.

I'm having trouble with the comparing and then making the new list by using the append function.

Here is part of the first input file:

```
Seq0
ATGGAAGCGAGGATGtGa
```

Here is part the second:

```
AUU     I
AUC     I
AUA     I
CUU     L
GUU     V
UGA     *
```

Here is my code so far:

```
input = open("input.fasta", "r")
codons = open("codons.txt", "r")

counts = 1
amino_acids = {}

for lines in codons:
        lines = lines.strip()
        codon, acid = lines.split("\t")
        amino_acids[codon] = acid
        counts += 1

count = 1

for line in input:
        if count%2 == 0:
                line = line.upper()
                line = line.strip()
                line = line.replace(" ", "")
                line = line.replace("T", "U")

                import re

                if not re.match("^[AUCG]*$", line):
                        print "Error!"

                if re.match("^[AUCG]*$", line):
                        mrna = len(line)/3
                        first = 0
                        last = 3

                        while mrna != 0:
                                codon = line[first:last]
                                first += 3
                                last += 3
                                mrna -= 1
                                list = []

                                if codon == amino_acids[codon]:
                                        list.append(acid)

                                        if acid == "*":
                                                mrna = 0

                                for acid in list:
                                        print acid
```

So I want my output to look something like this:

```
M    L    I    V    *
```

But I'm not getting even close to this. 
Please help!

Comment: Well for one, you never seem to be incrementing 'count'. Are you getting any output at all?

Answer (score 0):

The following is purely untested code. Check indentation, syntax and logic, but should be closer to what you want.

```
import re

codons = open("codons.txt", "r")
amino_acids = {}
for lines in codons:
        lines = lines.strip()
        codon, acid = lines.split("\t")
        amino_acids[codon] = acid

input = open("input.fasta", "r")
count = 0
list = []
for line in input:
    count += 1
    if count%2 == 0:    #i.e. only care about even lines
        line = line.upper()
        line = line.strip()
         line = line.replace(" ", "")
         line = line.replace("T", "U")

        if not re.match("^[AUCG]*$", line):
                print "Error!"
        else:
            mrna = len(line)/3
              first = 0
              while mrna != 0:
                  codon = line[first:first+3]
                  first += 3
                  mrna -= 1
                  if codon in amino_acids:
                      list.append(amino_acids[codon])
                      if acid == "*":
                          mrna = 0

for acid in list:
    print acid
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python there's usually a way to avoid writing explicit loops with counters and such. There's an incredibly powerful list comprehension syntax that lets you construct lists in one line. To wit, here's an alternate way to write your second `for` loop:

```
import re

def codons_to_acids(amino_acids, sequence):
    sequence = sequence.upper().strip().replace(' ', '').replace('T', 'U')
    codons   = re.findall(r'...', sequence)
    acids    = [amino_acids.get(codon) for codon in codons if codon in amino_acids]

    if '*' in acids:
        acids = acids[:acids.index('*') + 1]

    return acids
```

The first line performs all of the string sanitization. Chaining together the different methods makes the code more readable to me. You may or may not like that. The second line uses `re.findall` in a tricky way to split the string every three characters. The third line is a list comprehension which looks up each codon in the `amino_acids` dict and creates a list of the resulting values.

There's no easy way to break out of a `for` loop inside a list comprehension, so the final `if` statement slices off any entries occurring after a `*`.

You would call this function like so:

```
amino_acids = {
    'AUU': 'I', 'AUC': 'I', 'AUA': 'I', 'CUU': 'L', 'GUU': 'V', 'UGA': '*'
}

print codons_to_acids(amino_acids, 'ATGGAAGCGAGGATGtGaATT')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can solve the problem without regex, it's best not to use it.

```
with open('input.fasta', 'r') as f1:
    input = f1.read()

codons = list()
with open('codons.txt', 'r') as f2:
    codons = f2.readlines()

input = [x.replace('T', 'U') for x in input.upper() if x in 'ATCG']
chunks = [''.join(input[x:x+3]) for x in xrange(0, len(input), 3)]

codons = [c.replace('\n', '').upper() for c in codons if c != '\n']

my_dict = {q.split()[0]: q.split()[1] for q in codons }

result = list()

for ch in chunks:
    new_elem = my_dict.pop(ch, None)
    if new_elem is None:
        print 'Invalid key!'
    else:
        result.append(new_elem)
        if new_elem == '*':
            break

print result
```